# How to render the right content by using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

#### Steps to reproduce

```js
$dom.innerHTML = '<div><img src=".."><NonHtmlTag>text!</div>'
```

#### Expected

`<NonHtmlTag>text!`

#### Actually happening

`text!`
display in chrome:

#### Q:

what can i do to prevent `<NonHtmlTag>` from being recognized as an HTML element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a shot to ‘innerText’ property of html element. It put the content as the text only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Or see if ‘Node.textContent’ can work !
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: it won 't work，because i want the correct html `<img ....`